# pinescript - multiple entries that respects its own SL & TP

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm seeking assistance with Pine Script coding. I'm currently experimenting with the implementation of a simple strategy. In this strategy, each entry is assigned its own specific stop loss (SL) and take profit (TP). It's important that subsequent entries, such as a new long entry, do not impact the predefined SL and TP of previous entries, ensuring each entry maintains its independent risk and reward parameters.

Below is my code and i really really appreciate any help here.

> > `//@version=5
> > strategy("FakeySetup", overlay=true)
>
> > //Data Collection
> > CandleOpen = open
> > CandleHigh = high
> > CandleLow = low
> > CandleClose = close
>
> IsFlat() returns 'true' when the strategy has no open position.
> Returns 'false' when the script is long or short.
> IsFlat() =>
> strategy.position_size == 0
>
> > //CandleHighProximity = CandleHigh[1]-CandleHigh
> > CandleRangeBullish = (((close-open)/close)*100)
> > CandleRangeBearish = (((open-close)/close)*100)
>
> FakeySell = CandleHigh>=CandleHigh[1] and CandleClose<=CandleLow[1] and CandleRangeBearish<=0.5
> FakeyBuy = CandleLow<=CandleLow[1] and CandleClose>=CandleHigh[1] and CandleRangeBullish<=0.5
>
> > //Plot Signals to Chart
> > plotshape(FakeySell, location=location.abovebar, style=shape.triangledown, size = size.small)
> > plotshape(FakeyBuy, location=location.belowbar, style=shape.triangleup,size = size.small)
>
> > //@variable Stop-loss price for exit commands.
> > var float stoploss   = na
> > //@variable Take-profit price for exit commands.
> > var float takeprofit = na
>
> > //Entry Criteria for Fakey
> > if (FakeySell)
> > stoploss = (CandleHigh - CandleClose)
> > takeprofit = (CandleHigh-CandleClose)*2
> > strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)
> > strategy.exit("short", stop=(CandleClose+stoploss), limit=(CandleClose-takeprofit))
>
> if (FakeyBuy)
> stoploss = CandleClose - CandleLow
> takeprofit = (CandleClose-CandleLow)*2
> strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
> strategy.exit("buy", stop=(CandleClose-stoploss), limit= CandleClose+ takeprofit)

I noted that when the strategy is flat (no entries) everything works fine but when there are multiple signals I am kinda loss on what it does.